# FileEntry.getContentType() needs to be closed?

Tags: java, io, liferay, inputstream, liferay-6

Lets assume I have an `com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry` instance `fileEntry` that I'd like to copy.

I can achieve this using

```
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(...,java.io.InputStream is,...)
```

In this case, I get `InputStream` from my `FileEntry` using `fileEntry.getContentStream()`.

```
 FileEntry fileEntry;
 InputStream inputStream = fileEntry.getContentStream();

 FileEntry fileEntry2 = DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(repositoryId, folder.getFolderId(), fileName, mimeType, fileName, "file was created in " + new Date(), fileName + " updated", inputStream, size, serviceContext);
```

**Question** : Do I need to perform a `close` on that InputStream ?

```
StreamUtil.cleanUp(inputStream);
```

where `StreamUtil.cleanUp`:

```
public static void cleanUp(InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (_log.isWarnEnabled()) {
            _log.warn(e, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should but you do not have to.

Older versions of Java required that you close your `InputStream`. But in all JAVA versions that Liferay supports, the streams are automatically closed once all there are no more references. However, you are at the mercy of the garbage collector and its schedule.